# Image File Execution Options

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, regedit, virus-removal

My regedit keys in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options* have a lot of keys with the name of applications that I am sure that I have earlier removed as virus or malware, for example AppthgildeM.exe has two things

1. A default value of type 'REG_SZ'
2. A GlobalFlag of 'REG_DWORD' with a value 200 (I deleted this entry)

The rest of the keys with names of the malicious files only have the default value. I don't know the exact names of all the malicious entries so is there a way I can remove those?

The genuine entries have 'DisableExceptionChainValidation' set to 0 (thankfully) however explorer.exe has a value of 3. Should I change that back to 0?

Also for all the entries that I saw, they didn't have a debugger or any other key except for MitigationOptions set to 100 and a few specific ones like CFGOptions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registry keys always have a "default" value of REG_SZ type – this is a leftover from Windows 3.x era, when this was literally the only data format the registry had. (Hence the odd key/value/data terminology.)

As far as I know, "Image File Execution Options" places no significance on the subkey merely being *present* (which some other places of the registry do), so only non-default values are important here.

*DisableExceptionChainValidation* is always set to 3 for Explorer.exe, even on brand new installations. I can only guess this has something to do with third-party shell extensions, which load tons of (garbage) code into the Explorer.exe process.

*GlobalFlag* is a bit mask; each bit has [its own meaning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/gflags-flag-table). It seems having the bit 0x200 set enables some sort of [silent exit monitoring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/registry-entries-for-silent-process-exit), and I suspect it might be used as a way to automatically restart the malware process whenever it's killed (e.g. by having a Scheduled Task that's triggered by the event log entry).

Comment: Ah so I can just let them be without any problems. Is there any way to identify if the key was generated by a malware apart from some with obvious names or do I have to manually google for every key?